# Using the Stack Exchange API to update my user profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page, api

Is there any way to update my user profile (such as About me) using [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-types)?

If not, can this be added in the near future?

Having such API I'd like to write a script/app (e.g. using `curl`), to update my profile pages separately depending on the site context.

Answer (score 4):

I can see that the present API (v.2.2) does not return the contents of "About me" field in the /users endpoint.

It would be nice to at least read-only expose the field. However as a software engineer, you have to understand that each feature must be balanced against the costs and risks.

- How many users (and user apps) will programmatically access `About me`?
- How long does it take to add a field into the API?
- Are there security risks by exposing the field for write access?

It would be much better if your post contained guesstimate answers to the above questions to coherently argue for this feature to be implemented.