# What part(s) of our profile gets synced?

Tags: support, profile-page

I've registered to different SE sites, and got different **about me**s for at least 2 of them. Now, if I want to change my display name for all the sites except one but keep all the **about me**s intact, is there an easy way to do that? Should I use the old school copy/paste?

Comment: There is a feature request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254189/how-to-manage-multiple-profiles-across-se-sites) to add that functionality. Or maybe support [this FR](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254250/using-the-stack-exchange-api-to-update-my-user-profile) to extend the API so we can make such a feature....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there an easy way to do that?

No, not at the moment, I'm afraid.

> Should I use the old school copy/paste?

That's your best bet right now.